# AngularJS : How do you access ng-model's scope value within a directive that is using transclusion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, transclusion

I have an application controller that is responsible for adding users to another Model. There are two ways to add users in my application. We can add them by selecting the users themselves, or by selecting an entire group which will add all of the users of that group.

To make the UI a bit more friendly, I thought it would be a good idea to have tabs for adding users individually and through groups... that way I don't have to show both forms at the same time - the user can flip between the forms using tabs.

To implement tabs, I am using Angular Directives, since I use these tabs in other places in my application. Here is the html code to show you how the tabs are implemented:

```
<tabs class="tabsContainer">
    <tab-pane title="Users" class="users">
        <form name="usersForm" ng-submit="addUsers()">
            <label>Select Users Here:</label>
            <select name="selectedUsers" ng-model="selectedUsers"
                    multiple="true" ng-multiple="true"
                    ng-options="user.id as user.fullName for user in users">
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Add Users</button>
        </form>
    </tab-pane>
    <tab-pane title="User Groups" class="userGroups">
        <form name="userGroupForm" ng-submit="addUserGroups()">
            <label>Select Groups Here:</label>
            <select name="selectedUserGroups" ng-model="selectedUserGroups"
                    multiple="true" ng-multiple="true"
                    ng-options="userGroup.id as userGroup.name for userGroup in userGroups">
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Add User Groups</button>
        </form>
    </tab-pane>
</tabs>
```

In the controller for this HTML, I'd love to get access to the `tab-pane`'s ng-model values for `selectedUsers` and `selectedUserGroups`. I would have thought that since they are defined as transcludes, that the scope would be the application's controller itself, but I think the scope value is actually in the `tab-pane` directive's scope. This means that in my main application controller, `$scope.selectedUsers` and `$scope.selectedUserGroups` is not defined.

If I temporarily remove the `tabs` and `tab-pane` directives, everything in the main controller works. So I think those directives are hidding `ng-model` when they are transcluded within a `tab-pane`.

How do I get access to it?

Comment: directive allow scope inheritance and two way binding. It means that you can assing ng-model from your parent scope and any changes at child scope will bind back to parent scope.

Comment: @hutingung how do I tell tab-pane that whenever `ng-model` is set inside of the `transclude` block that parent scopes can access it? I know how to get 2-way binding in so many other cases, but I think this is a weird exception to the rule. I have a lot of working angularjs code and 200+ directives... this is just the exception to the rule.

Comment: Prior to angularjs-1.3, ng-transclude will create nested scope. Refer to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5489 . You can try the workaround.

Comment: If you can create plunkr for this, I will help to try the workaround.

Comment: Actually, with your help, I figured it out. Both `tabs` and `tab-pane` needed: `transclude(scope.$parent, function(content) { element.append(content); });` at the top of their link function. I had to remove `ng-transclude` from the templates of both directives. It works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @egervari You should add this as an answer and mark it as such.